# GraphResponse is failing for /me/accounts facebook graph request

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating Facebook SDK for android with Pages Api.

Goal is to allow logged on Facebook user (using offical app) to post videos to any one of the pages that he/she is a Admin of.

I have created facebook page and am able to successfully login using following code.

```
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("pages_show_list", "pages_manage_posts", "pages_read_engagement"));
```

After this I run following code,

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(getAccessToken(), "/me/accounts", null, HttpMethod.GET, null);
```

and pass the `graphRequest` instance to an `AsyncTask` for execution like below.

```
GraphResponse response = graphRequest.executeAndWait();
Log.d("graphresponse", "" + response.toString());
```

the log is always following.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: GraphRequest can't be used when Facebook SDK isn't fully initialized}}
```

What am I doing incorrect over here?

1. Is `/me/accounts` correct graphPath? Or should it be `me/accounts` without preceding `/`?
2. [facebook apis Step 1. Get Your Page ID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started/)  Referring to this page I want to iterate over available pages, get their ids and access tokens and then publish to first page found with `CREATE_TASK` task. Is this correct way? If not, how do I allow user to select a page for publishing video to after logging in?
3. <s>The `AccessToken` always contains only two permissions `public_profile` and `pages_show_list`.
   Why am I not getting `pages_manage_posts` and `pages_read_engagement` permissions in `AccessToken`?</s>

EDIT : I am getting following permissions with a different account.
`permissions":["user_status","pages_manage_metadata","public_profile","user_events","business_management","pages_manage_ads","pages_read_engagement","user_photos","user_birthday","pages_manage_posts","user_posts","pages_show_list","pages_manage_engagement","email","pages_read_user_content"]`

But still `GraphResponse` for the request is the same.

Comment: Did you even _read_ the error message …?

Comment: yes. i did read it which was pointing to GraphRequest cannot be used when FacebookSdk isn't fully initialized. I was confused by the responseCode of 200.
That made me think it was permissions error. Silly mistake I know. Issue was I was conditionally executing FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize() if FacebookSdk.isInitialized() was false. Silly, I know..But thanks for pointing out to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Got the code working.

The only issue was instead of calling `FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize()` in `onCreate()` I was calling the following code.

```
if(!FacebookSdk.isInitialized()){FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize();}
```

On removing the `if` condition it worked fine.